# How to format a perl oneliner?

Tags: shell, perl

If I have a perl one liner running it from the command line: e.g

```
perl -MData::Dumper -MJSON=decode_json -e 'my @array = @{decode_json($data)}; foreach my $i (@array) { etc }'
```

How could I format it so that it is more readable i.e. add new lines? If I do something like:

Ma

The command breaks when I add the new lines like that to format the code

Comment: One could wonder why they are called one-liners ...

Comment: Maybe you should write a real Perl script and save it in an executable file if it is complicated enough that you don't want to have it on one line…

Comment: Fair point guys. Just thought it could look a bit nicer

Comment: It can. Perl can write in script files, and then you can use things like `perltidy` to make it consistently formatted, and you can use longhand variable names and line wrapping and everything.

Comment: I my opinion one-liners are loathsome beasts that should never be part of production code.

Comment: *"If I do something like `Ma`"*?

Comment: Absolutely. One liners should really be for one shot use. E.g. throw away code. If you need to keep it, it should be a script.

Comment: See also https://github.com/perltidy/perltidy/issues/58

Answer (score 6):

Write an actual perl script?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings; 

use JSON qw ( decode_json );

my $json = decode_json ( do{ local $/; <> } ); #read from stdin/file specified on command line

foreach my $element ( @$json ) { #iterate
   # do things
}
```

Otherwise - you can add linefeeds in between your quotes - they've no semantic significance, unlike some other languages.

So:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -MJSON=decode_json -e '
    my @array = @{decode_json($data)}; 
    foreach my $i (@array) { etc }
'
```

But seriously - if you're looking at making a *one liner* more readable, then the answer is 'write it as a script, that's what they're for'.

Comment: But if at the command line I press enter after `-e '` it breaks

Comment: What platform are you using? Works fine on mine?

Answer (score 4):

As others already said, if your *oneliner* is too complex to fit into one line, you should use a script.

In some rare cases (and when the script is debugged and working), you can inline the perl script into your `bash` script as:

```
#!/bin/bash

# bash function which prints the perl script
perlcode() {
cat - <<'PERLCODE'
use scrict;
use warnings;
# ... rest of your script
PERLCODE
}

#and use the inlined script as    
perl <(perlcode)
```

The above works because it uses the `bash`'s [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) mechanism, where first is executed the commands enclosed in the `<(...commands...)` and the stdout of result is acts as an temporary file.

So, the `perl <(perlcode)` first execute the `perlcode` bash function, (which just prints the perl source code), and in the next step the bash uses the result as

```
perl /dev/fd/63 #some temporary file descriptor
```

e.g. exactly as `perl /path/to/script`. Such inlined perl script is works as ordinary perl script and for example could contain the `__DATA__` section too.

You must use the quoted `<< 'HEREDOC'` form to avoid variable expansion.

But really, only becasuse you *can* do something like the above, **doesn't mean that you should**. It is always much better to have a perl script in some file alone.

Answer (score 0):

This is funny: You want to have a **one-liner**, which, for readability, should span **several** lines. This sounds like a contradicition.

What you **can** do is to drop the `-e` switch and make a HERE document:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -MJSON=decode_json <<ENDOFPERL
  # Your multi-line one-liner goes here
ENDOFPERL
```

Comment: that sounds interesting. What if I had other options e.g. `-n`?

Comment: I don't see why this should be a problem, i.e. `perl -nlp input_data.txt <<ENDOFPERL`. Of course using a HERE-Doc always means that your stdin is taken; the solution doesn't work if you want to feed your data via a pipe.